# How do I properly handle variable (creditted) amounts via PayPal APIs?

Tags: api, paypal

I'm looking for a way to allow our clients to do recurring payments to discount these payments based on the credit in their account which can be earned or deposited in many ways. For example, if they need to pay $20 and have $5 in credit, I would like to only bill the remaining $15 automatically without any need for additional website visits.

Looking at the documentation for PayPal's REST APIs, I don't see any clear way to do this. Is the only way to do this to send them a refund automatically? Or is there a way to get approved to bill clients up to X amount per month but allow us to bill under that amount. I thought billing agreements would allow for this, but after reading the documentation, I'm unable to figure out a way to do it. If it's possible, could someone walk me through what API calls would be needed to do this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: It is not clear where you are lost, thus what you need. Certainly billing agreements do allow you to bill users a variable amount, e.g. based on usage, in amount & schedule that you determine (and manage outside PayPal).

Comment: @geewiz What APIs would be used to do that with billing agreements? I was under the impression it was possible with billing agreements but was unsure of how to do it.

Comment: If you want to use PayPal's REST product, start here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements

Comment: If you want to use PayPal's reference transaction product (which also uses "billing agreements" -- not the same ones, but the same name), start here:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: @geewiz Thanks, I've seen those but I don't see how you would use the billing agreements REST API to do this, I don't see any way to change the amount on a month-to-month basis. Do you need to use the classic API for this?

Comment: See Andrew's answer below. He's spot on; the REST stuff is PayPal's newest product set and does still have some functionality gaps vs the earlier, more mature products. If the REST has functionality gaps that you can't live with then use the Pro suite or the Adaptive product (and of these I personally recommend the Pro product, reference transactions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you could do this sort of thing, but I would avoid the REST API for now.  It's still too new and doesn't provide as much functionality and features as the classic API.

Within the classic API, you can use either use [Preapproved Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/), which consists of [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) APIs, or you could just use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) and/or [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) with [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/).

Either way you'd basically be building your own recurring payments system where you'd setup a billing agreement and then your app would trigger the variable amount payments accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like great info, but is there no way to do this with the new REST APIs at all? Seems strange.

Comment: It looks like Preapproval and Pay is exactly what I was looking for. I'll work with those in the Classic APIs for now I suppose.

Comment: PayPal added REST to compete with what Stripe and others are doing.  Developers seem to think it's more simple.  It's brand new, though, and it's way behind what Classic gives you.  I see a LOT of times where people start with REST and then end up switching to Classic because REST just doesn't give them what they need.  As such, I recommend just sticking with classic.  They're not going anywhere, and if you're working with PHP [my class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) makes it very quick and easy.